# jQuery redirect after time

Tags: jquery, redirect, settimeout

I try redirect to index.php with this script writte

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#product").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).hide(1000);
        jQuery("#products_s").hide(10);
        setTimeout("location.href='index.php", 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

The little script i create works but i can´t get redirect to index after the click over the link in div , i supose redirect ok , i think it´s write ok but sure the people of here can help me and see the fails

Only y get close the div but no redirect

Thank´s , Regards

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing quote in your `setTimeout`. I would change it to something like this to avoid evals and make it easier to see syntax errors:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    location.href = 'index.php';
},1000);
```

Comment: I don't understand the context of "avoid evals"... if eval were to run here - it would be run at the global scope and not at local scope. / which is fine. p.s. (sharp eyes. didn't notice the missing `'`)

Comment: @RoyiNamir If you pass a string to `setTimeout`, that string has to be `eval`'d, which is a bad thing.

Comment: @JasonP Yes . but the worst thing eval can do is when it is on your local scope. this is not the case. setTimeout runs at global window object. it does not have access to your local variables. also there is no user input here. so i dont see any reason for mention eval. and FYI - this is one of the tecniques to use eval as global evaluation.

Comment: @RoyiNamir There are also performance and maintainability concerns. See [eval is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Typo mismatched quotes

```
setTimeout("location.href='index.php'",1000);   
                                    ^ add single quote here
```